# Can not use controller name in laravel, must use namespace

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravelcollective, laravel-controller

[Blade view and PostsController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVjAI.png)

When I use `{!! Forms::open(['method'=>'post', 'action'=>'PostsController@store']) !!}`
It errors out.

But when I use `{!! Forms::open(['method'=>'post', 'action'=>'App\Http\Contollers\PostsController@store']) !!`
It works.

Why cant I just use Controller name instead of namespace name?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In RouteServiceProvider.php uncomment
protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';
this line

Answer (score 3):

You could use instead the route name like that

```php
 Form::open(['route' => 'route.name'])
```

for example, creating a post should be something like that

```php
Form::open(['route' => 'posts.create'])
```

for more info check the docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#opening-a-form)

Answer (score 0):

As per [ [PSR-0](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/), [PSR-4](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) ] coding standard we have to use namespace in code.

In your case, if you don't write the full path you can simply use:

1. 'action'=>"{{ route('route_name') }}"
2. 'action'=>"{{ url('url_name') }}"